# Getting line of onscreen output as parameter for command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line, zsh

In bash (or zsh), is there a way to 'look back' on previous output?

Say I have the following:

```
$ find . -depth 1 -name "d*"
dir1
dir2
dir3

$ cd [3rd line]
```

Can I pluck 'dir3' from the previous output without repeating the previous command and using a pipe?  Just sort of "grab it" from onscreen?

Comment: Quick research shows bash doesn't keep any history of its output.  I'm assuming this isn't possible.

Comment: Do you use bash or zsh?

Comment: I use zsh.  I'd be interested in a bash solution as well just because it's so common.

Comment: `tmux` provides a copy mode in which you can scroll back through the terminal buffer, copy a block of text, and paste it onto the command line after you exit copy mode.

Answer (score 1):

The shell doesn't see that output *at all*. When `find`runs, it uses the file handle that it inherits from the shell to write *its* output, but that isn't visible to the shell (though even if it were, the shell isn't caching it).

---

However, given that you are using `zsh`, the first question you should ask involving an external command is, "Do I even need the external command?" As is often the case, you don't here. Instead of using `find`, just use `print` and a glob to get the same listing:

```
% print -l d*
```

then use the same glob again with a qualifier to select the 3rd result.

```
% cd d*([3])
```

(This assumes that the expansion of `d*` won't change between running the `print` command and running the `cd` command.)

Or, you can cache the result yourself:

```
% choices=( d* )
% print -l $choices
dir1
dir2
dir3
% cd $choices[3]
```

The array-based solution could work in `bash` as well, though with slightly different syntax (and assuming your `find` command is simple enough to be replaced with one of `bash`'s far less powerful globs.)

Finally, there is the `select` command:

```
select d in d*; do
  cd "$d"; break;
done
```

which will also work as-is in `bash`, again assuming a valid glob.

Answer (score 0):

A cursory search reveals neither bash nor zsh provide this functionality.  Happy to be corrected if there's a way to do this. :)